# How to use call() for inheritance. Error: Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor

Can you explain me how to implement inheritance when using `class`?

When I use `function` for defining the constructor, everything works (cf. code version 1). But when I turn `function` into an ES2015 `class` (version 2) it produces this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Person cannot be invoked without 'new'

Do I need to add something to the code or should I just leave it as it is with `function`?

#### 1. Working code using `function`

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

function Customer(firstName, lastName, phone, membership) {
  Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.phone = phone;
  this.membership = membership;
}

const customer1 = new Customer("Tom", "Smith", "555-555-555", "Standard");
console.log(customer1);
```

#### 2. Failing code using `class`

```js
class Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}

class Customer {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, membership) {
    Person.call(this, firstName, lastName); // <--- TypeError
    this.phone = phone;
    this.membership = membership;
  }
}

const cust1 = new Customer("Bob", "Johnes", "555-222-333", "Silver");
console.log(cust1);
```

Comment: The first one worked because you called Customer() with new keyword. That makes the function behave like a constructor function. So when the function ran, it initialized `this` to {}, which was passed to Person when you did `Person.call...`, classes in js are syntactical sugar on top of these constructor functions, except for the fact that they cannot be called without new keyword. Hence second one doesnt work

Comment: It also links up the constructor, so you can do `(new Customer(...)) instanceof Person`, which is `true`.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, it is not allowed to do `Person.call()` when `Person` is defined with `class`. ES2015 offers the `extends` and `super` keywords for achieving such prototype-chain definition:

```
class Customer extends Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, membership) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
    this.phone = phone;
    this.membership = membership;
  }
}
```