# Is it possible to indirectly call the constructor function where X is an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is related to [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064489/how-to-use-call-for-inheritance-error-class-constructor-cannot-be-invoked-wi) but I'm specifically asking about extending a new ES6 class using the old way of writing a function.

The following code doesn't work.

```js
class X {
    a;
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
X.call({}, 3); // Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor X cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Is there a way to indirectly call the constructor function? For example, is it possible for me to use the old-fashioned prototypical inheritance to make a Y?

```js
function Y(a) {
    X.call(this, a); // this doesn't work here, can't use super as well
}
Y.prototype = Object.create(X.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Y, X);
const y = new Y(12);
```

Comment: I'm curious, why use a traditional function rather than `class` when you're extending a constructor created with `class` and you're using ES2015+?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) and [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target):

```
function Y(a) {
    return Reflect.construct(X, [a], new.target || Y);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class X {
    a;
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

function Y(a) {
    return Reflect.construct(X, [a], new.target || Y);
}
Y.prototype = Object.create(X.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Y, X);
const y = new Y(12);
console.log(y.a); // 12
```

or if you want to pass along all provided arguments:

```
function Y(...args) {
    return Reflect.construct(X, args, new.target || Y);
}
```